# Codeigniter different DB for each language

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I'm using codeigniter and the project i'm working on has to be in two languages.

The only thing i can't figure out is how to select a different database in codeigniter when a session variable is set to a certain value.

example:

if the session variable 'language' is set to 'EN' i want it to select the DB:
"databasename_EN"

in all other cases select DB:
"databasename_EN"

The only thing i found was that you can do $this->db->load('bla'); but this means you have to add a DB-load in every model and you have to disable autoload 'database'.

Comment: You do realize, you just said you always want to select DB: `datebasename_EN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the best result I would create a pre_system hook that checks whether a $_SESSION['lang'] variable exists and if it does set a constant:

```
define('LANG', isset($_SESSION['lang']) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : 'EN');
```

Then in your database config file do this:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "database_".LANG;
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Should do the trick with minimum fuss.

Answer (score 3):

A variation of Phil Sturgeaon answer:

```
$active_group = LANG; // switch the DB based on the LANG constant

$db['EN']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['EN']['username'] = "root";
$db['EN']['password'] = "";
$db['EN']['database'] = "databasename_EN";
// etc

$db['FR']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['FR']['username'] = "root";
$db['FR']['password'] = "";
$db['FR']['database'] = "database_FR";
//etc
```

Comment: That would be handy to set different database encoding for the different languages, but other than that you would simply end up repeating username/password configurations for each language.

Comment: I agree, in this case changing the database name should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you could create a MyModel class extending Model and handling this gymnastic. than all you'd need to do is use MyModel as the parent class of your models.

Comment: you might want to take a look at this has well http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html